Using python to query splunk and get SID - error 404
I have this query (below):

When I run this query in Splunk web, I get back SID and get data using SID.
When I use curl command, I get back SID and get data using SID.
But when I use Python, I get SID in the response with status code 201.

with open("aquery.txt", "r") as f:
        aQuery = f.read()
    
        finalAQuery=('search'  + '%20' +('earliest%3D' + str(nowStartTimestamp)) + '%20' + ('latest%3D' + str(nowEndTimestamp)) + '%20' + aQuery)
    TOKEN='Bearer 12345'
url ="https://abc.splunkcloud.com:8089/servicesBB/-/abc-ccc_local_app/search/jobs"
    def getSid():
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, headers={'Authorization':TOKEN}, data={'search': finalAQuery}, verify=False)
            global sid
            results = response.text
            root = ET.fromstring (results)
            sidphrase = root.find('sid')
            sid=sidphrase.text
            print("SID from getSid    method: " +  sid)    
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print("Error fetching data:", e)
            return results

I get back the SID. But when I use the SID to get the results, I get error 404, <Response [404]> {"messages":[{"type":"FATAL","text":"Unknown endpoint."}]}
def getMetric():
    try:
        getData=(url + '/' + sid + '/results')
        getSidResponse = requests.get(getData, headers={'Authorization': TOKEN}, data= {'output_mode' : 'json'}, verify=False)

#aquery.txt contents below.
index=apigee sourcetype="abc:Prod_access_logs" | rex field=proxyUri "(?P<proxyUri>(([a-zA-Z]+)\d)(?:\d\/[a-zA-Z]+|\/[a-zA-Z]+)+)" | convert num("requestTimeinSec") |rex field=_raw "(?<timeStamp>\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}T\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})\s+(?<hostValue>\w+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(?<requestTimeinSec>\S+)\s+\-\s+-\s+(?P<httpStatusCode>\w+)\s+(?<upstreamHttpStatusCode>\w+)\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(?<methodName>\w+)\s+(?<proxyUri>\S+)\s+(?<httpVersion>\S+)\s+(?<messageId>\S+)" |rex field=_raw "^([^\t]+\t){35}(?P<ClientId>[^\t]+)" | eval totalResponseTime=round(requestTimeinSec*1000) | replace "z1/credit/bank/info/usa" with "x1/credit/bank/info/canada" in proxyUri | replace "v1/taste" with "/connecticut/taste/v1/newyork" in proxyUri | rangemap field="httpStatusCode" "httpStatusCode"=0-499 | rename range as RangeSuccesshttpStatusCode | eval Product=case(like(ClientId, "JERSEY"), "aaa", like(ClientId, "APPLE"), "bbb", like(ClientId, "HELLO"), "ccc") | eval ATier=case((like(proxyUri,"/abc/jersey/v1/newyork") AND like(methodName,"POST") AND IN (Product, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")) , "Tier1", (like(proxyUri,"v1/credit/bank/info/canada") AND like(methodName,"GET") AND IN (Product, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")) OR (like(proxyUri,"v1/credit/accounts/profile") AND like(methodName,"GET") AND IN (Product, "Venmo", "Cobrand", "PPC")), "Tier2",(like(proxyUri,"v1/alarm/prefer") AND like(methodName,"GET") AND IN (Product, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")), "Tier3",1==1,"NA") | stats count(totalResponseTime) as TotalTrans, count(eval(RangeSuccesshttpStatusCode="httpStatusCode")) as TotalSuccesTran, count(eval(httpStatusCode<500)) as GoodEvents, by ATier Product proxyUri methodName | where ((Product IN ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")) AND (ATier IN ("Tier1", "Tier2","Tier3"))) |rename methodName AS Method | fields ATier proxyUri Method TotalTrans GoodEvents

Curl command that works:
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $BEARER" https://abc.splunkcloud.com:8089/servicesAB/-/abc-bbb_local_app/search/jobs -d search='earliest=-15m@m latest=now index=apigee sourcetype="apigee:Prod_access_logs" | rex field=proxyUri "(?P<proxyUri>(([a-zA-Z]+)\d)(?:\d\/[a-zA-Z]+|\/[a-zA-Z]+)+)" | convert num("requestTimeinSec") |rex field=_raw "(?<timeStamp>\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}T\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})\s+(?<hostValue>\w+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(?<requestTimeinSec>\S+)\s+\-\s+-\s+(?P<httpStatusCode>\w+)\s+(?<upstreamHttpStatusCode>\w+)\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(?<methodName>\w+)\s+(?<proxyUri>\S+)\s+(?<httpVersion>\S+)\s+(?<messageId>\S+)" |rex field=_raw "^([^\t]+\t){35}(?P<ClientId>[^\t]+)" | eval totalResponseTime=round(requestTimeinSec*1000) | replace "z1/credit/bank/info/usa" with "x1/credit/bank/info/canada" in proxyUri | replace "v1/taste" with "/connecticut/taste/v1/newyork" in proxyUri | rangemap field="httpStatusCode" "httpStatusCode"=0-499 | rename range as RangeSuccesshttpStatusCode | eval Product=case(like(ClientId, "JERSEY"), "aaa", like(ClientId, "APPLE"), "bbb", like(ClientId, "HELLO"), "ccc") | eval ATier=case((like(proxyUri,"/abc/jersey/v1/newyork") AND like(methodName,"POST") AND IN (Product, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")) , "Tier1", (like(proxyUri,"v1/credit/bank/info/canada") AND like(methodName,"GET") AND IN (Product, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")) OR (like(proxyUri,"v1/credit/accounts/profile") AND like(methodName,"GET") AND IN (Product, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")), "Tier2",(like(proxyUri,"v1/alarm/prefer") AND like(methodName,"GET") AND IN (Product, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")), "Tier3",1==1,"NA") | stats count(totalResponseTime) as TotalTrans, count(eval(RangeSuccesshttpStatusCode="httpStatusCode")) as TotalSuccesTran, count(eval(httpStatusCode<500)) as GoodEvents, by ATier Product proxyUri methodName | where ((Product IN ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")) AND (ATier IN ("Tier1", "Tier2","Tier3"))) |rename methodName AS Method | fields ATier proxyUri Method TotalTrans GoodEvents'


Please update the question to include the curl command that works.

Added curl command
